# Variadic function template base case: without parameters or with one?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, c++14, variadic-functions

I would like to know which one of these (if any) options would be preferred.

For example I'm implementing a sum function taking arbitrary number of arguments. The main template is then

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
auto sum(T t, Ts... ts)
{
    return t + sum(ts...);
}
```

For the base case I can see at least two options:

1. Base case is sum():

   ```
   auto sum() 
   { 
       return 0; 
   }
   ```
2. Base case is sum( T ):

   ```
   template <typename T>
   auto sum(T t)
   {
       return t;
   }
   ```

Both of those seem to work in the same way in this case, but which one would be generally preferred?

Comment: I think the second case is better because the first one add an operation for no argument

Comment: Try both and measure. You'll probably find that they end up with the same assembly after optimization.

Comment: I would use the first simply because one day you might actually _need_ the version with zero arguments in your other code.

Comment: 2nd version would compile little faster. I would rather choose a version with at least 2 arguments, because a *logical* sum can happen between 2 numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second case is more generic than option 1 which introduce `int`.

ie: with your second option, you could `sum` some matrix class, whereas the first one disallows that. (You should take argument by const reference to be efficient for matrix case though).

By introducing `int`, you also have different return type for some case as

```
auto res = sum('*');
```

which result in `int` type for option 1 and in `char` type for option 2

Comment: *more generic* suggests there is only this one criterion. But there's at least one other, as pointed out by Petr: Whether or not `sum(t...)` works for `sizeof...(t) == 0`. (But it's still a valid question what type `sum()` should have.)